# Solver VBA ignoring constraints and conditions on macOS

Tags: macos, excel, vba

I have solver vba code working fine on Windows (Excel 2013), but there are some problems on macOS with Excel 2011. Here is a code :

```
SolverReset
SolverAdd CellRef:="$CB$2:$CB$" & LastRow, Relation:=5, FormulaText:="binary"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$CA$3", Relation:=1, FormulaText:="100000"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$CA$10", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="8"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$CA$7", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="3"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$CA$8", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="3"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$CA$9", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="=1"
SolverOptions MaxTime:=100, Iterations:=100, precision:=0.000001, Convergence:= _
0.0001, StepThru:=False, Scaling:=False, AssumeNonNeg:=True, Derivatives:=1
SolverOptions PopulationSize:=100, RandomSeed:=0, MutationRate:=0.075, Multistart _
:=False, RequireBounds:=True, MaxSubproblems:=0, MaxIntegerSols:=0, _
IntTolerance:=0, SolveWithout:=False, MaxTimeNoImp:=30
SolverOk SetCell:="$CA$4", MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$CB$2:$CB$" & LastRow,
_ Engine:=2, EngineDesc:="Simplex LP"
SolverSolve
```

Problem is that following conditions are missing from solver after applying above code :

```
SolverAdd CellRef:="$CB$2:$CB$" & LastRow, Relation:=5, FormulaText:="binary"
SolverOk SetCell:="$CA$4", MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$CB$2:$CB$" & LastRow,
_ Engine:=2, EngineDesc:="Simplex LP"
```

One interesting thing is that only SetCell and ByChange is not set up from second condition, but engine type "Simplex LP" is fine. 
I got the code from by recording macro which I setted up manually, so there should not be any problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it after a lot of wasted time. It seems that there is a problem with "_" characted in  :

```
SolverOk SetCell:="$CA$4", MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$CB$2:$CB$" & LastRow, _
Engine:=2, EngineDesc:="Simplex LP"
```

I solved it on following way :

```
SolverOk SetCell:="$CA$4", MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$CB$2:$CB$" & LastRow
SolverOk SetCell:="$CA$4", MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$CB$2:$CB$" & LastRow, _
    Engine:=2, EngineDesc:="Simplex LP"
```